# I need help on xpath expression for getting the value

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

I have a query as follows I need to get a column and its values under 
 
Ex. first value is AR_GROUP_EMAIL_ID in XML.

I am not able to figure what should be xpath expression.

```
      select a.* from  (select  prf_code_xml    from myxmltab )  xmltab       
       ,  XMLTable(
       '/PivotSet'
       passing xmltab.prf_code_xml 
                 columns
       prf_Code  varchar2(20) path  '/PivotSet/item/column[1]'
      ) a
```

XML:

```
<PivotSet>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">AR_GROUP_EMAIL_ID</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">AUTO_ASN_RECEIVE</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">AUTO_EMAIL_PREF</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">AUTO_INVOICE_PREF</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">BOLT_GL_ENABLED</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">CALC_AUTO_FREIGHT</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">CHECK_PO_VENDOR</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">DISTR_SYNC</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">ENG_VAL</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">FA-ENABLED</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">FA_CREATE_USER</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">FA_DELAY_TIME</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">FREIGHT_ON_BO</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">IQA-RA_ENABLED</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">IQA_SENDER</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">IQA_TARGET</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">IQA_WAIT_TIME</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">ONESOURCE_ENABLED</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">ORDER_UPDATE</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">PO_SHIP_VIA_LOV_CHECK</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">PRODWISE_SUGG_ORDERS</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">QSSM_ASSET</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">QSSM_CONTACT</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">QSSM_CUST_SITE</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">QSSM_RESP_TIMEOUT</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">QSSM_SENDER_ID</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">QSSM_SERV_WO</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">RDC_ENABLED</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">REP60_OP_PATH</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">REP_PATH</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">RPT_URL</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">SENDER_ID</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">SPECIAL_SHIP</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">SPR_MONTHS</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">TARGET_ID</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">TRIM_SCANNER_SPACES</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">UPDATE_OE</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">VENDOR_LOV_CHECK</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">WO_REPORT_FILLER</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
    <item>
        <column name="PRF_CODE">WO_RPT_PRINT_TC</column>
        <column name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)">1</column>
    </item>
</PivotSet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the item node in the XPath:

```
select a.prf_code
from myxmltab
cross join XMLTable('/PivotSet/item'
  passing myxmltab.prf_code_xml
  columns prf_Code varchar2(20) path 'column[1]'
) a;

PRF_CODE           
--------------------
AR_GROUP_EMAIL_ID   
AUTO_ASN_RECEIVE    
AUTO_EMAIL_PREF     
AUTO_INVOICE_PREF   
...
```

I've taken out the redundant inline view to simplify it a bit. And rather than relying on the column node order always being the same (though that may be a valid assumption) you could use the column name instead:

```
  columns prf_Code varchar2(20) path 'column[@name="PRF_CODE"]'
```

If you want both columns you can add a second term:

```
select a.prf_code, a.quantity
from myxmltab
cross join XMLTable('/PivotSet/item'
  passing myxmltab.prf_code_xml
  columns prf_Code varchar2(20) path 'column[@name="PRF_CODE"]',
    quantity number path 'column[@name="COUNT(PRF_CODE)"]'
) a;

PRF_CODE               QUANTITY
-------------------- ----------
AR_GROUP_EMAIL_ID             1
AUTO_ASN_RECEIVE              1
AUTO_EMAIL_PREF               1
AUTO_INVOICE_PREF             1
...
```

Comment: Thank you ..  That answers my question.  I would like to however ask how would I get the attribute value of the tag in this case "PRF_CODE"  , I tried using Column[1]@name but its not useful.

Comment: @milindbrahme - `name varchar2(30) path 'column[1]/@name'`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !! . Marking this answered.